# Nginx ingress error 404 using host and path

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I'm using Kubernetes on Azure cloud, and I have installed zipkin.
I already install nginx ingress, and if I use the following host rule, it works fine:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
    - host: zipkin.hostname.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: zipkin
              servicePort: 9411
```

But this is not what I want. What I want is something like hostname.com/zipkin.

I tried with this, but I got a 404 error:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /zipkin
          backend:
            serviceName: zipkin
            servicePort: 9411
```

What do I have to do?

Edit:
I tried to add the host and after doing a describe command i get this

```
Name:             NAME
Namespace:        NAMESPACE
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host           Path  Backends
  ----           ----  --------
  hostname.com
                 /zipkin   zipkin:9411 (10.244.0.63:9411)
```

EDIT:
I solved my issue adding a rewrite rule annotation

```
nginx.org/rewrites: >
      serviceName=zipkin rewrite=/;
```

Comment: What DNS do you want to use? Your own DNS or anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't mentioned the `host` here:

```
spec:
  rules:
  -  host: hostname.com // here
     http:
      paths:
        - path: /zipkin
          backend:
            serviceName: zipkin
            servicePort: 9411
```

Comment: I already tried this. But then if I access at hostname.com/zipkin i have a 404 white label error page
i tried to do a describe of the ingress and i obtain this
Name:             NAME
Namespace:        NAMESPACE
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host           Path  Backends
  ----           ----  --------
  hostname.com
                 /zipkin   zipkin:9411 (10.244.0.63:9411)

Comment: I edited my original question with the formatted result of the describe command

Answer (score 0):

First, previous answer is wrong, you don't need to specify `host` it is not mandatory unless you want to set up a DNS.

Second, the backend `zipkin` requires the `/zipkin` URI to respond right? If this is the case, then the rewrite annotation is removing the URI. So you would need to change your yaml like this to pass `/zipkin` to your backend.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /zipkin
          backend:
            serviceName: zipkin
            servicePort: 9411
```

Comment: no, what i want is that /zipkin will be rewrite on / on the backend. I solved my issue using this annotatation nginx.org/rewrites: > serviceName=zipkin rewrite=/;
I'll add to my question

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the OP problem.

There are different [ingress Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/)

Note:

> When you create an ingress, you should annotate each ingress with the appropriate ingress.class to indicate which ingress controller should be used if more than one exists within your cluster.
>
> If you do not define a class, your cloud provider may use a default ingress controller.
>
> Ideally, all ingress controllers should fulfill this specification, but the various ingress controllers operate slightly differently.

Using this annotation:

```
nginx.org/rewrites: >
      serviceName=zipkin rewrite=/;
```

It looks like you are using NGINX Ingress Controller provided by nginxinc.

You can find more information about **Rewrites Support** for NGINX Ingress Controller provided by [nginxinc here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/rewrites).

example:

```
nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=service1 rewrite=rewrite1[;serviceName=service2 rewrite=rewrite2;...]"
```

It's different from the kubernetes community at [kubernetes/ingress-nginx repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md#rewrite-target).
Different ingress controllers have different configs and annotations.

So for this example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=my-nginx rewrite=/"
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hostname.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-nginx
          servicePort: 80
        path: /zipkin
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

Test it:

```
curl -vH 'Host:hostname.com' xx.xxx.xxx.xx/zipkin


* Connected to xx.xxx.xxx.xx (xx.xxx.xxx.xx) port 80 (#0)
> GET /zipkin HTTP/1.1
> Host:hostname.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.17.5
< Date: Mon, 28 Oct 2019 12:21:48 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 612
< Connection: keep-alive
< Last-Modified: Tue, 22 Oct 2019 14:30:00 GMT
< ETag: "5daf1268-264"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
```